# c- Use different shared libraries in the main program and the so loaded inside the program

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, elf

My main program needs to call standard openssl functions such as `SSL_library_init()`. On the other hand, the program needs to load a library, say mylib.so, that utilizes a modified version of the openssl.

The main program is compiled using

```
-L/path-to/orig-openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Moreover, mylib.so is made using

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path-to/modified-openssl/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

options.

When I execute the program, it tries to load the modified version of the openssl rather than the original one.

How can I enforce the program to use the original openssl inside the main program while use the modified version inside the called library, mylib.so?

Note 1: If I use `-rpath,/path-to/orig-openssl/lib` to compile the program, the program will load the true (original) openssl. However, when it tries to load mylib.so, it fails (dlopen cannot open the library).

Note 2: Using `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag inside the `dlopen` function causes the same results.

Comment: use static linking for your lib

Comment: Never a good idea to incorporate modified packages such as this one into your code.  if you need additional functionality that this library does not provide, create your own supplemental library, being careful to keep naming conventions for your custom library separate from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer:

Use `dlmopen` with `LM_ID_NEWLM` flag to load mylib.so in the main program.

Moreover, to compile the main program, use `-Wl,-rpath,/path-to/orig-openssl/lib` for dynamic linking. In other words, you should set the rpath for the shared object and the main program.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I enforce the program to use the original openssl inside the main program while use the modified version inside the called library, mylib.so?

In short, you **CAN'T**.

There is no way to reliably do what you're asking.

You have conflict between the requirements of `mylib.so` - which expects a customized version of OpenSSL - and your code, which requires a "normal" version of OpenSSL.

OpenSSL is not designed to allow multiple, different instances of itself to exist in a single process.  There will be unpredictable symbol conflicts - where code that expects a function or variable to do or be one thing gets a symbol for function or variable that does or is something different - a function that expects different parameters or a structure with different fields, for example.

Even if you somehow contrive a way to make things appear to work, what are you going to do when you have to upgrade your OpenSSL version because of a new vulnerability, and that upgrade breaks your workarounds?  And you can't find a way to fix them and get things "working" again?  (And I do hope you're not ignoring the need to upgrade OpenSSL with your modified version of OpenSSL - how are you planning on rolling out an emergency fix to **that** when the next high-priority security-related vulnerability in OpenSSL is published?)

If you have to use two distinct versions of OpenSSL, you need to do that from two separate processes.